# how to add ipv6 support for my vm?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have just created a VM to which I want external client contact via some port eg. 1788/tcp. How do I do this? I found some sources suggesting the use of Load Balancers, but which one should I use and how?

From this StackOverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53018915/12429357):

> HTTP(S), SSL proxy and TCPproxy load balancers accept IPv6 connections from clients and then proxy those connections to the backend instances using IPv4. You will find details [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ipv6).
>
> SSL Proxy load balancer supports ports 25, 43, 110, 143, 195, 443, 465, 587, 700, 993, 995, 1883, and 5222.
>
> TCP Proxy load balancer supports the following ports: 25, 43, 110, 143, 195, 443, 465, 587, 700, 993, 995, 1883, 5222.
>
> Load balancing on port 80 is only provided by the HTTP(S) load balancer.
>
> So in your case, if you want to use port 80 for IPv6 termination, the only option in GCP is to use the HTTP load balancer.

I also do not find my ports listed here.

Answer (score 0):

Every external GCP load balancer can [accept IPv6 clients](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ipv6).

For assistance in picking which one, refer to the [Choosing a load balancer flow chart](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/choosing-load-balancer). Note that proxy type load balancers restrict ports and protocols, but offer more features. External TCP/UDP Network Load Balancing offers arbitrary ports, but is not a proxy. Instead, network load balancing terminates on the backend instances, with direct server return.

---

IPv6 directly to instances is not supported. They left the [UserVoice request for IPv6 from 2013](https://googlecloudplatform.uservoice.com/forums/302595-compute-engine/suggestions/8518246-support-ipv6) open acknowledging this.

Answer (score 0):

Google cloud now supports external ipv6 on VM instances. Each instance can get a /96 external ip range and it can be used to access internet (without NAT) or be used for VM to VM traffic.

At this moment (July 2021) it's only supported limited regions:

- asia-east1
- asia-south1
- europe-west2
- us-west2

See more detailed in

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/configure-ipv6-address

https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc#ipv6-addresses